# The given key was not present in the dictionary. Even when dictionary.ContainsKey("given_key") == true

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dictionary

I have a class that gathers 7-day forecast data from the Bureau or Meteorology and presents it on a web page. A script runs every 30 minutes to get updated data from the Bureau.

The bureau provides data in a tab delimited format with a header row. After extracting all the fields, I put the values into a `Dictionary<string,string>` for parsing. For obvious reasons, the important field for organising the data is the "forecast_date". So before I begin parsing, I make sure that my dictionary actually contains this key.

Here is a very simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
static object ForecastLockingObj= new object();
private void UpdateWeather()
{
    if(isTimeForUpdate())
    {
        lock(ForecastLockingObj)
        {
            if(isTimeForUpdate())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> ForecastData = Get7DayForecast();
                int forecastDate = int.MinValue;
                if (ForecastData.ContainsKey("forecast_date") && int.TryParse(ForecastData["forecast_date"], out forecastDate))
                {
                    //Parse the data
                    SetNextUpdateTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This actually works for the most part. But very occasionally I'll get the following exception:

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +28
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +7457036
   CoA.WebUI.Controls.WeatherWidget.UpdateWeather() in C:\dev\WeatherWidget.cs:231
```

Where line 231 is the if statement that checks the existence of "forecast_date" then attempts to parse it into an integer. Note; the service reliably renders dates as integers (e.g. 20130515) and so this is more of a sanity check.

`ContainsKey` should not be throwing this exception, so I feel it must be where I refer to `ForecastData["forecast_date"]` in my TryParse.

My question is this; surely if ContainsKey returns false, then TryParse should not run. So why would it report the existence of a key in one statement and then deny its existence in the very next statement... whilst we are inside a lock and the Dictionary we're working on is non-static and local?

As an aside; this typically happens in the afternoon, when the Bureau releases the next long range forecast. The exception happens for a few page-loads and then rights itself.

---

Here is the full Get7DayForecast method

```
private Dictionary<string, string> Get7DayForecast()
{
    int linenumber = 0;
    int locationNameKey = 0;
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> myLocationData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ForecastURL);
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

    FtpWebResponse ftp_response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();

    if (ftp_response.WelcomeMessage.StartsWith("230") && ftp_response.StatusDescription.StartsWith("150"))
    {
        Stream ftp_responseStream = ftp_response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader ftp_reader = new StreamReader(ftp_responseStream);

        while (ftp_reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            linenumber++;
            string line = ftp_reader.ReadLine();
            List<string> temp = (List<string>)line.Split(ForecastDelimiter).ToList<string>();
            if (linenumber == 1)
            {
                //Break if the header line does not contain the fields we require
                if (!ForecastRequiredFields.All(line.Contains)) { break; }
                keys = temp;
                locationNameKey = keys.IndexOf(ForecastLocationFieldName);
            }
            else if (temp.Count == keys.Count && temp[locationNameKey] == ForecastLocationName)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    myLocationData.Add(keys[i], temp[i]);
                }
                //Break if we've just parsed the data we were looking for
                break;
            }
        }

        ftp_reader.Close();
    }
    ftp_response.Close();
    return myLocationData;
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that the dictionary is defined inside a lock? I figured anything defined within the lock is thread safe.

Comment: By the `lock` statement, I assume that you are using multiples threads. There isn't other methods excluding itens from the same object returned by `Get7DayForecast`?

Comment: Hmmm... no `Get7DayForecast` is only used by `UpdateWeather` inside the `lock` statement. It is also largely encapsulated; except for the FTP address of the service (yes... FTP) and the code for the City we're trying to get data on, all objects are defined in the method.

Comment: I agree with @fhelwanger.  I'm not sure how the `lock` would protect you as you are locking forecastLockingObject but the changing data isn't part of that object.  Did you try to `lock` ForecastData before this statement?  As said in the previous comment, Get7DayForecast or some other method must be changing this object.

Comment: Ok, `Get7DayForecast` is only used there, but the object returned by it isn't used in other places? (You can have two variables pointing to the same object).

Comment: The lock would protect access from multiple threads to the ForecastData dictionary returned by Get7DayForecast, as long as any other code that accesses that object also used the same lock. What does Get7DayForecast do?

Comment: Okay, I checked. The object returned by `Get7DayForecast` is defined and created inside the method - each call to `Get7DayForecast` returns a new `Dictionary<string,string>`. That object is then pointed to only once, and implicitly disposed of at the end of the method.

Comment: @Wayne, I'll add this to my question details, thanks :)

Comment: Can you post `Get7DayForecast`?

Comment: Stack trace line numbers can be wrong. The exception may be happening on another line. Look closely at every line where you access the dictionary by key and consider whether it could be throwing the exception.

Comment: My gut tells me I'm getting back something unexpected in the Bureau data and I'm not handling it correctly. I think I'll start dumping what I get back from FTP to a file until it happens again so I can check. It strikes me as odd that it only happens in the afternoon or evening.

Comment: Thanks @IgbyLargeman, I think you may be onto something. It just doesn't make sense to me - given how I've set everything up - that I should be getting an exception on that particular line. I mean, it's entirely possible I've missed something and it is a collision, but I have this nagging feeling that it's not that. I will report back if I find anything.

Comment: Just curiously why are you not using TryGetValue()? Probably won't fix the problem at a fundamental level, but if you are doing a check and get value it is a cleaner way to do this

Comment: Yeah, no reason other than a slip of the mind really. I'll be changing this when I deploy the new dll.

Comment: Maybe use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I cannot see why your code would fail but you should consider taking advantage of `Trace` to see what is up. Also it couldn't hurt to use `TryGetValue` instead.

```
var map = Get7DayForecast();

string forecastDateString;
if (!map.TryGetValue("forecast_date", out forecastDateString))
{
    Trace.WriteLine("forecast_date entry was not found.");
    return;
}

int foreCastDate;
if (!int.TryParse(forecastDateString, out foreCastDate)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Value was not a valid integer: " + forecastDateString);
    return;
}

SetNextUpdateTime();
```